# vertical line in tabular problem

Tags: tables

im trying to create a table with a vertical line at the left and at the right, EXCEPT the top row shouldn't have the vetical lines.
something like:

```
  A  B  C
| a  b  c |
| a  b  c |
| a  b  c |
| a  b  c |
| a  b  c |
```

I have this code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|cr@{}lr@{}lr@{}l|}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{P} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{E} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{D} \\
\hline

pond &10&&8&,9&6&,2\\
\hline\hline

euro &11&,3&10&&7&,0\\
\hline\hline

dollar&16&,2& 14&,3&10&\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

How to fix it so that it doesnt add a vertical line to the top row?
thx in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}` for the first cell instead of leaving it empty